# scope in javascript without the keyword var

Tags: javascript, scope

```js
function jjj(asi) {
  asi=3;
}

jjj();
console.log(asi);
```

Here I am thinking that `asi` is a global variable but while running this code it is giving that `asi` is not defined.

As per the books and official doc I have studied that if you mention the variable name without the keyword var then it becomes global so I think same rule applies to asi variable also

Comment: You’re not defining a global variable. You’re redefining the parameter of the function.

Comment: @xufox I think that parameter is variable which we can use in our other parts of the code

Comment: You mean using the parameter `asi` outside of the function? No, this is definitely not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> here I am thinking that asi is a global variable but while running this code it is giving that asi is not defined

It would be creating an implicit global **if** you weren't declaring it as a parameter instead, e.g.:

```js
function jjj() {
//           ^---------- removed `asi` here
  asi = 3;
}
jjj();
console.log(asi);
```

Note that implicit globals are *a really bad idea* (I called my blog post on them [*The **Horror** of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) for a reason) and you should use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to make them the errors they always should have been:

```js
"use strict";
function jjj() {
  asi = 3; // ReferenceError: asi is not defined
}
jjj();
console.log(asi);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case the function argument is reassigned with a new value.

```js
function jjj(asi) {
  asi = 3 // the function argument will have new value
  mno = 4 // this will be a global variable
}
jjj();
console.log(asi);
console.log(mno);
```